# Patch compressed file

Tags: gzip, patch

is there any way to patch a file, that is compressed via gzip without decompressing it first? I tried

```
patch -n <(gzip -d file.gz) patch_to_file.diff > new_file
```

but I only got

```
patch: **** Can't create temporary file /dev/fd/63.o65LeZA : No such file or directory
```

as a result.

I'd like to avoid the storage overhead, so if there is any way to do this with pipes/process substitution I'd be very happy. :)

Comment: If the patch that you have is for the uncompressed data, then you must uncompress the data to patch it.  Since patching a file changes it, you would additionally have to re-compress the data after patching.  This is assuming that you don't have a binary patch for the compressed file itself (in which case you would not be able to use `patch`, which is for text files).

Comment: @Kusalananda Not disagreeing, but there are tools like zless which allow transparently exposing the plain text contents of a file without manually requiring a decompression step first. In a parallel universe, a tool like `zpatch` could exist which would answer the question. (Unfortunately?) we don't live in that universe, though :)